# How to solve jenkins error: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

i have a jenkins currently running on the google cloud platform and i get an error when running the pipeline and I do not exactly where the problem is.

```
@NonCPS
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil

String getVersion(String path) 
{
   def version = new XmlSlurper().parse(new File(path))
   return version.toString()
}

node {
  withEnv (['versionFileName=version.xml'])
  {
    stage('checkout')
    {
      cleanWs()
      checkout scm
    }
    stage('Version')
    {
      def foundVersion = getVersion("${versionFileName}")
      sh "echo Found version [Version $foundVersion]"
    }
  }
}
```

I get the following error when i run the pipline. This happens in the Version stage because i inserted some echos for debugging and found out this happens when it calls the getVersion method

```
script.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Comment: This pipeline code compiles, which means the issue is in an invoked method or function. Therefore, we cannot assist without further information about those.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem. I needed to include the working directory for the getVersion method to work.

```
stage('Version')
{
   def wd = pwd()
   def foundVersion = getVersion("${wd}/${versionFileName}")
   sh "echo Found version [Version $foundVersion]"
}
```